# Does the Town Hall count toward the Architect mission?

Tags: vikings-gone-wild

In Vikings Gone Wild, The Architect Mission requires the player to have built 5 different types of buildings. Does the Town Hall count as one of those types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got the answer straight from the Publisher [on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1703510/question-regarding-architect-mission):

> Excellent question! No it does not!